# Weblogic session timeouts don't extend as expected

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

Using Weblogic and I've got my session timeout in my web.xml set to 30 minutes.  Users get 30 minutes, but any activity after that only extends 5 minutes.

So for example on the 28th minute, the user will do some activity to the server.  7 minutes later the user is forced off as the session times out.

Expected behavior would be to get another 30 minutes, that the session timeout should be the time SINCE last activity.   However it appears that Weblogic only increases your time in 5 minute increments.

Tomcat on the other hand (which Im not allowed to use) works as expected, you get a full 30 min from time of last activity.

Does anyone know of any internal Weblogic setting that might control how much time the user gets after the initial session timeout length?